# Why can't one dynamically declare an array of objects in C++ like this :

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic-arrays

In my C++ project, there is a class which needs to create an array of objects.
Between different instances of the class, the size of the array will be different, which is why I chose to use an array.

If I do :

```
int numberOfPlayers; // This is determined at run time.
int *players; 

//In constructor
players= new int[numberOfPlayers]; // This works
```

But if I do:

```
Character *players;
players = new Character[numberOfPlayers]; // Compiler complains
```

The Compiler complains "No matching constructor for initialisation of Character"

How do I dynamically declare an array of type "Character".

Note: Character has nothing to do with char. Character is a name of an class I created myself.

EDIT: Character does not have a default constructor, since it needs to be passed several arguments so it can be initialised with the proper state. The only constructor is has takes several arguments.

EDIT: I chose a dynamically created array, over a vector since I know during the lifetime of the instance, the size of the array will be constant, though between different instances the size will be different. I thought this would make sense for performance reasons (memory / speed).

Comment: Note that `new` is one of the least practical ways to create an array. Consider using `std::vector`.

Comment: Yes, with a `std::vector`, you don't even have to worry about this default constructor business.  See my answer below.

Comment: Did you write the `Character` class?  Sometimes the lack of a default constructor is deliberate, and implies that a `Character` object may not be meaningful until some construction parameters are available - you can wait until you have them then `push_back` or `emplace` elements in a `std::vector<Character>`, which is generally easier to use properly than using arrays and `new`.

Comment: Yes. I wrote the Character class, and there is no default constructor because the object will not be meaningful until some construction params are available (like you said). I thought since the size of the array won't change during the lifetime of the class a dynamically allocated array is better than a vector.

Comment: @John: In order to create an array of objects, the compiler needs to call *a* constructor of the class for each object. Because `new[]` does not permit to pass any argument to the constructor, the compiler is forced to use the default constructor.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The "proper" way is to use `std::vector`. It is a fast, safe, more robust alternative to horrible `new`.

```
std::vector<Character> vec;
vec.push_back(Character(params));
vec.push_back(Character(other_params));
```

If you know the size ahead, you can avoid reallocation overhead by using `std::vector::reserve`

```
std::vector<Character> vec;
vec.reserve(50);
vec.push_back(Character(params));
vec.push_back(Character(other_params));
```

The overhead of `std::vector` is practically non-existent.

Now, the reason why you can't do this your way, it's because by default `new` uses default constructor, and it doesn't exist.

Comment: Better than my explanation.  Good examples.  +1

Comment: `emplace_back` avoids the temporaries. e.g. `vec.emplace_back(params);`

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that your type `Character` does not define a default constructor of the form:

```
Character::Character()
{
   // etc.
}
```

Comment: What if it doesn't make sense to have a default constructor ? Character needs several arguments to initialise it to the proper state.

Comment: @John: Then don't give it one. But don't create dynamic arrays this way. Use `std::vector` instead. In fact, use `std::vector` even if you *do* have a default constructor.

Answer (score 3):

Your type needs a default constructor.  Unlike C's `malloc`, `operator new` constructs instances for you at the time of allocation.  It then follows that it requires a parameterless (default) constructor as it provides no way to pass arguments. So...

```
class Character
{
public:
    Character(){}
};
```

Comment: I don't think a default constructor makes sense for me, since Character requires several pieces of information before it can be initialised to a "correct' state. Do you think malloc makes more sense in this case ? Is there a better alternative ?

Comment: @John: `malloc` with non-POD types results in UB, so no.  You need a default constructor.  I commiserate as I can appreciate wanting to make sure that all of your required data is present, but you'll just need to supply defaults.  Just use a `std::vector`, that's really how you should be handling this anyway.  That said, you should also learn how memory allocation works in C++.

Answer (score 3):

*"Character does not have a default constructor, since it needs to be passed several arguments so it can be initialised with the proper state. The only constructor is has takes several arguments"*

Then an array is the wrong type to use, because an array will always default-construct its members.

Use:

```
std::vector<Character> players;
```

The size can vary, as you wanted, and you can `call players.push_back( character )` when each character has been constructed

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that you can't do this because the standard doesn't allow it. There's no technical reason it *couldn't* be allowed--it just isn't.

Some compilers (e.g., gcc) have supported it as an extension to C++ for years. It's also been supported in C by various compilers for long enough that C99 standardized it, so all (reasonably current) C compilers now support it.

There was a proposal to add an array-like class with a size determined when it was created, and remaining constant after that, but the committee decided against accepting it<sup>1</sup>. That leaves only `std::array`, which requires a size determined at compile time, and `std::vector`, with a size that can vary dynamically at run time.

In fairness, however, if you do know the size of a vector when you create it, you can specify the size at creation time. While it's certainly still *capable* of resizing itself, that functionality is mostly in `resize` and `push_back`. If you simply don't use those, the overhead from using `std::vector` compared to a native array is generally quite minimal anyway, so you're unlikely to see significant gains from other techniques (except, perhaps, under rather obscure circumstances).

---

<sup>1. At least IMO, this was the right decision--although I can see the basic reasoning behind the *idea*, I think the proposal was sufficiently flawed that we're better off without it.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Because allocating an array of `Character` means that the array will contain an amount of `Character` instances. When you allocate the array, each instance contained must be initialized somehow and the default constructor is required.

You have to declare `Character::Character() { }` to let the compiler invoke it. If you can't provide a default constructor then you should consider using a `Character**` so that you can init them as you wish, eg:

```
Character **array = new Character*[amount];
array[0] = new Character(...);
```

Mind that this requires to delete each instance, so instead of having `delete[] array` you will need

```
for (int i = 0; i < amount; ++i)
  delete array[i];
delete [] array;
```

An additional way would be to forget about arrays and use a `std::vector`:

```
vector<Character> character;
character.push_back(Character(...));
```

Which would also relief the need to manage memory by yourself.

Comment: Since I know that the size of the array will be fixed for the lifetime of the class, will the vector use unnecessary amounts of memory / be slower ?

Comment: @John: performance is irrelevant until proven otherwise. You shouldn't worry about writing efficient code, first you should worry about write correct and maintainable code, then you can consider performance. For your purpose, chances are that the difference in performance is negligible.

Comment: @John Note that the "array of pointers" approach it waaaaay slower (n+1 memory allocations) and takes much more memory than using `std::vector`.

Comment: I guess I'll use a vector then. Can you explain why it uses more memory ? Shouldn't it be similar since we will will only store the same number of Character objects ?

Comment: @John You first allocate array of pointers AND the `Characters` (that is `(sizeof(Character)+sizeof(Character*)) * amount`), plus every single `Character` object is allocated separately (that's why it's slow).

Comment: @John A dynamically allocated array in this manner is exactly the same as vector. If you want to be EXTREMELY picky, you can do `std::vector<Character> characters; characters.reserve(numberOfPlayers);` and it will give you at least numberOfPlayers elements in the vector. You can then use emplace_back to construct things in place. For the love of god, please don't run around manually newing and deleting arrays. That's a surefire way to bring hell down around your head later on.

Comment: Finally, `-1` for you: double-pointers for lazy initialization? Seriously?